# Blank option in filter. But where is it coming from?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, data-modeling

I created two custom columns in Date table and they return True or False values.

There are no blank values in either of these two columns in the Date table.

However, when I use these columns as filters, there appear to be Blank options.

Selecting and displaying the blank values returns results. Where are these blank values coming from?

[image: Custom columns and filters]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Blank* means you have values in the many side table of your relationship which do not exist on the one side table of your relationship.

Comment: To expand a bit on this: When this happens, Power BI inserts an "invisible" blank row in the one-side table, to match any rows on the many-side that do not exist in the one-side. You can't actually see it in the table view.

Comment: Thank you, both. One of my fact tables has rows with where Date values are blank. I guess this is what's causing it.